# Баластний, контрастний, шістнадцять, але чесний, радісний. Чому?

Tags: правопис, приголосні

Слова "Контрастний", "баластний" - іншомовного походження, "шістнадцять", "чесний", "радісний" - власне українські.

Підпорядковуючись яким правилам відбуваеться спрощення?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Питання, як мовиться, хрестоматійне.

§ 19.1

Спрощення груп приголосних

У групі приголосних **-С(Т)Н-** випадає **т**: ти́ждень — ти́жня — тижне́вий; ко́ристь — кори́сний

Винятки: зап’я́стний, кістля́вий, пестли́вий, хвастли́вий, хвастну́ти, хворостня́к, **шістна́дцять** літера т зберігається.

Примітка. У прикметниках, утворених від іменників іншомовного походження з кінцевим -ст, літера т у групі приголосних -стн- зберігається, хоч відповідний звук і не вимовляється: аванпо́ст — аванпо́стний, **бала́ст — бала́стний**, компо́ст — компо́стний, **контра́ст — контра́стний**, форпо́ст — форпо́стний.

[Український правопис](http://www.pravopys.net/)